# Howto encrypt user password without a username

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, webhooks

I'm consuming a webservice. It's sending me a json string and a secret so I can validate the incoming data.

I have build an endpoint in python with flask that saves the incoming json to a database.
Before the incoming data is processed I validate the secret.

Now I would like to keep the secret in a database. Normally I would encrypt the secret before I save it in the database and I would save it together with a userID. Then I would look up the userID at get the encrypted secret and validate id.

My problem is that the webservice doesn't send a userID, only the secret.

so I need to lookup the encrypted secret in the database by the secret. In the mysql request i could look something like this:

```
sql = "select encrypted_secret from table where 'True' = " + pbkdf2_sha256.verify(secret, encrypted_secret)
```

Obvios this makes no sense because I can't refer to the encrypted secret before the query has been executed.
As an alternative I could query all the secrets I have in the database and see if the incoming secret is one of them but it doesn't seam to be a good solution.

How would you handle this?

BR Kresten

Comment: For what purpose are you storing the secret? Do you want to a validate if it changes? (if so a salted hash is sufficient).

Comment: Fist I want to validate if it came from some bandit of from the webservice, second I need to link to secret to some other date I have in the table.

Comment: PBKDF2 requires a salt to work. Is that salt static for all secrets or is there are random salt for each secret? The former has a simple solution. The latter has not. Also, if the secrets have sufficient entropy which passwords have not then you don't need PBKDF2 and might use a simple hash function such as SHA-256.

Comment: I think I understand now. My secret is a long strong random string, and because salt basically is a random string added to a weak to so random string its already build into my secret and therefore I don't need salt.
Thanks